# Position animated icons and remove overlapping using CSS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to position the icons to the right and the tags to the center. 
My website is using BootStrap and Font-Awesome. Below is the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Health</span>
    </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Fitness</span>
    </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Safety</span>
    </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <i class="fa fa-heart faa-pulse animated" style="float:right;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <i class="fa fa-star faa-pulse animated" style="float:right;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o faa-pulse animated" style="float:right;"></i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="post-header" style="text-align: center">This is the header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
}

.faa-pulse.animated,
.faa-pulse.animated-hover:hover,
.faa-parent.animated-hover:hover > .faa-pulse {
  -webkit-animation: pulse 2s linear infinite !important;
  animation: pulse 2s linear infinite !important;
  font-size:1.8em;  
}
.fa-heart {
    color: red !important;
}
.fa-star {
    color: gold !important;
}
.fa-smile-o {
  color: deeppink !important;
}
```

The problem is my icons are overlapping with each other during animation and the tags are not aligned to the center. Also,there is very little space between the icons. How can I solve this problem?

Here is the [demo](https://www.bootply.com/iK944PvPgZ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Re-formated HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Health</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Fitness</span>
    </a>

    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Safety</span>
    </a>
    <span class="animated-icons"> 
    <i class="fa fa-heart faa-pulse animated"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-star faa-pulse animated" ></i>
    <i class="fa fa-smile-o faa-pulse animated" ></i>
    </span>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.animated-icons {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: @SenjutiMahapatra Your Welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to do this,

from user guide example http://fontawesome.io/examples/

> Use fa-fw to set icons at a fixed width. Great to use when different icon widths throw off alignment. Especially useful in things like nav lists & list groups.

```
 <div class="row">

   <!-- edited (1) -->
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center;position: relative;">
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Health</span>
    </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Fitness</span>
    </a>
    <span>&nbsp;</span>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none;">
      <span style="background-color: #171717; color: #FFF; padding: 2px">Safety</span>
    </a>  

    <!-- edited  (2) -->
    <div style="position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;">
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-heart faa-pulse animated" ></i>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-star faa-pulse animated" ></i>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-smile-o faa-pulse animated" ></i>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <h1 class="post-header" style="text-align: center">This is the header</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

or u could change css

```
.faa-pulse{
  margin:3px;
}
```

see this https://jsfiddle.net/jayakrishnancn/73Lfxnpg/3/

Comment: Yes. This is partially right. But what about the tags "Health", "Safety" and "Fitness". They are shifted to the left. They should be aligned to center.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding margin to the font Awesome Icons

```
i.fa
{
  margin:4px;
}
```

Hope this helps.. :D

Comment: Yes. This is partially right. But what about the tags "Health", "Safety" and "Fitness". They are shifted to the left. They should be aligned to center.

Comment: hi.. why can't u try something like this https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/JJoVBZ?editors=1100

Comment: The tags are not associated directly with the icons. The tags can be more or less than the number of icons

Comment: hi.. try this https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/JJoVBZ?editors=1100